# Custom font doesn't work with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a custom font in CSS but it does not work.

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Shout!</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Jordan Baron">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <img src=images/logo.png alt="logo" height="54" wdth="133" class="logo">
      <hr class="divider">
      <h1 id="wis">Shout!</h1>
    </div>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">    </script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: SanFran;
  src: url(SF-UI-Display-Thin.otf);
}

div {
  text-align: center;
}

.divider {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

.logo {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

.wis {
  font-family: SanFran;
}
```

I am using Bootstrap 3 on Mac OS X. I am using Chrome.
The font changes when I don't use Bootstrap but when I do use Bootstrap the font doesn't change

Comment: where does `SF-UI-Display-Thin.otf` located

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't change because you're using an ID on your `<h1>` but you're trying to target a class of `.wis` instead of an ID of `#wis`.

Try changing

```
.wis {
  font-family: SanFran;
}
```

to

```
#wis {
  font-family: SanFran;
}
```